# Should we merge [sumeria] into [sumer]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merge

While looking for interesting tags to watch, I happened to notice that we have both [sumer](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sumer) (currently with 15 questions) and [sumeria](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sumeria) (with 3 questions), both presumably referring to the bronze-age civilization and region of [Sumer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sumer) in southern Mesopotamia.

I'm tempted to just edit and retag the three questions tagged with [sumeria](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sumeria) but, given that I'm a relatively low-rep user on this site, I thought it prudent to check for community consensus first.

I've posted a self-answer describing my proposed plan of action below; you're welcome to either upvote it or post your own answer describing what you feel should be done instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[sumeria](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sumeria) has been merged into [sumer](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sumer), and made synonyms to prevent future misuses.

I want to commend you for making the right decision bringing this up on Meta instead of editing yourself. In general, users *should not* manually edit tags in bulk, as this will spam the frontpage. Instead, moderators has the ability to merge and synonymise tags silently, avoiding the disruption of bumping old questions en masse.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, [sumeria](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sumeria) is a redundant (and misnamed) duplicate of the pre-existing [sumer](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sumer) tag.**

The few questions currently using it should be retagged so that this duplicate tag will get removed from the system.